# How to use Microsoft.Graph to update a contact?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I'm using Microsoft Graph to change contacts's phone.

```
var defaultContact = await graphClient.Me.Contacts.Request().GetAsync();

mylist.AddRange(defaultContact);

while (defaultContact.NextPageRequest != null)
{
    defaultContact = await defaultContact.NextPageRequest.GetAsync();
    mylist.AddRange(defaultContact);
}
```

I have a list of contacts: mylist

I use this code for add a new contact:

```
await graphClient.Me.Contacts.Request().AddAsync(newcontact);
```

But I can't find how to update or edit a contact by use Microsoft.Graph

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you want to edit/update an contact you can use the following operation:

```
PATCH /me/contacts/{id}
PATCH /me/contactFolders/{id}/contacts/{id}
```

or

```
PATCH /users/{id | userPrincipalName}/contacts/{id}
PATCH /users/{id | userPrincipalName}/contactFolders/{id}/contacts/{id}
```

there are a few more operations (but basically the same) described in the [documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/contact_update).

In the C#-SDK this can look like this:

```
/* ... do your changes to the contact*/;

// PATCH /users/{id | userPrincipalName}/contactFolders/{id}/contacts/{id}
var request = await graphClient.Users["userId"].ContactFolders["contactFolderId"].Contacts[myChangedContact.Id].Request().UpdateAsync(myChangedContact);
```

Or

```
// PATCH /me/contacts/{id}
var request2 = await graphClient.Me.Contacts[myChangedContact.Id].Request().UpdateAsync(myChangedContact);
```